# Add 'articles' prefix before blog posts url without affecting pagination

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, pagination, rewrite-rules

I tried this solution for adding 'articles' prefix before blog posts on URL.

```
function filter_post_link($permalink, $post) {
if ($post->post_type != 'post')
    return $permalink;
   return 'articles'.$permalink;
}

add_filter('pre_post_link', 'filter_post_link', 10, 2);

function add_blog_rewrites( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $wp_rewrite->rules = array(
    'articles/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]',
    'articles/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]',
    'articles/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
    'articles/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'articles/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'articles/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
    'articles/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&tb=1',
    'articles/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'articles/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'articles/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
    'articles/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
    'articles/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]',
    'articles/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]',
    'articles/[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
    'articles/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'articles/[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
    'articles/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
) + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_blog_rewrites' );
```

Everything working fine except pagination cause problem, i got 404 error on "articles/page/2/" & so...

I don't want to put "/articles/%postname%/" on permalink since there are few different custom post, taxonomy etc.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... Any clue?